# SIP Client - JsSIP login issue in my server

Tags: sip, sip-server, jssip

I am creating an web application. In which I have to integrate the text, voice and video chat via SIP server. So that I have chosen the "JsSIP" from http://tryit.jssip.net/. I am trying to chat in the demo screen. It is working good. So I downloaded the code and put into my apache server.

Now I am open the login screen and trying to login. But it throws the following error.

```
WS connection error:
- WS close code: 1006
- WS close reason:
```

Can anyone tell me what may be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide more information and a code sample